# Get collection of executing asynchronous WCF calls

Tags: wcf

I have a UI which calls a WCF method called 'LongRunningProcess'- WCF has generated me the asynchronous method 'BeginLongRunningProcess' as such (assume client object is pre-configured):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    WCFObject.BeginLongRunningProcess(null, null);
}

Application.Exit();
```

Assume this long running method runs for an hour. The result is 5 asynchronous calls taking place on the WCF server, while the UI has closed.

The question is, how do i get a list of those executing threads, and cancel one of them? Is it even possible?

Problem:

1. How do i get the list of threads
2. How can i identify the threads from each-other (can i tag them when i call them?)

Thanks

Comment: how do you spawn threads on server side?

Comment: my apologies, i did not explain correctly how i made this call. The call is made using WCF's 'Allow generation of asynchronous operations' - the method on the WCF service is just 'LongRunningProcess' - but WCF generates me an async method called 'BeginLongrunningProcess'

Comment: In what way do you want to be able to check the threads?  From within the same app domain as the WCF host?  From an external process monitor tool?  The ease or difficulty depends on from where you are wanting this info, and what you plan to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I begin my answer, I wanted to address some ambiguity introduced by the question:

The WCF, or more specifically, the web application hosting the WCF, will create a new service instance to concurrently execute any service call regardless of whether asynchronous methods are generated when creating the service consumer classes on the client.  The asynchronous methods are solely for the benefit of the client, so that a service call may be made, the client may continue executing, and then the results from the call may be requested at an arbitrary time later.  (Normally, you would execute the MyService.BeginMyMethod call, and at some point later execute the MyService.EndMyMethod.)

Now to address the question, I'll take the easier path, and assume that you want the WCF host to track its currently long-running methods.  For the service to know about its long-running methods, you can simply maintain your own static list.  A simple code example:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public static List<Task> MyRunningTasks = new List<Task>();
    private static object MyRunningTasksLockObject = new object();

    public void StartMyLongRunningMethod()
    {
        var myTracker = new MyProcessTrackingClass()
        {
            OwnerName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
            StartTime = DateTime.Now
        };
        var myAction = new Action<object>(userState => 
            {
                var myActionTracker = (MyProcessTrackingClass)userState;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
                    myActionTracker.PercentComplete += 10M;
                }
            });
        var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(myAction, myTracker, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        AddLongRunningMethod(myTask);
        myTask.ContinueWith(t => RemoveLongRunningMethod(t));
    }

    private static void AddLongRunningMethod(Task item)
    {
        lock (MyRunningTasksLockObject)
        {
            MyRunningTasks.Add(item);
        }
    }
    private static void RemoveLongRunningMethod(Task item)
    {
        lock (MyRunningTasksLockObject)
        {
            MyRunningTasks.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class MyProcessTrackingClass
{
    public string OwnerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public Decimal PercentComplete { get; set; }
}
```

The body of `myAction` in the example above is where your method logic would go (or you could just invoke a separate method from that point).  Additionally, this approach provides a few other benefits.  For one, the service method itself is merely creating a `Task` which will do all the heavy lifting, so the method will in fact return a response quickly to the client, so it doesn't even matter if you create asynchronous methods on the client side or not.

Another benefit is that since your service knows the running processes, you could even expose another service method that would allow clients to query current long-running processes, like so:

```
public IEnumerable<MyProcessTrackingClass> ListLongRunningProcesses()
{
    return MyRunningTasks.Select(t => (MyProcessTrackingClass)t.AsyncState);
}
```

As is pointed out in that last example, the `AsyncState` property of each `Task` holds our custom class, passed in as the `state` argument of the `StartNew` method which created the `Task`.  You can update the `MyProcessTrackingClass` to include any properties you desire to associate with the running methods.

Comment: What a fantastic answer. Thank you- from a brief read of it, it looks like it will solve my problem. I'll give it ago and come back :)

Comment: @TomBeech I've updated my answer to include a nifty feature made available by my process, by introducing the MyProcessTrackingClass.PercentComplete property.  Updates made to userState will reflect in the object when it is returned via ListLongRunningProcesses.